# PHP buffer overruns

Tags: php, security, buffer-overrun

Are there any known points to be careful about buffer overruns in PHP?  Currently I take an email address from a form, run it through `preg_match` to check it's only a single address, call the `mail` function with it, and store another load of form data in a database using `PDOStatement::bindValue()`.

Anything to worry about?

Comment: Do you expect something along the lines of "don't use `preg_match`, it buffer overflows!"? Then... sorry, no. Check http://bugs.php.net if you want to be up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if it's possible to write code in PHP that contains buffer overflow vulnerabilities, then the answer is no. You can't have those in PHP, it manages the memory for you and you can't directly alter the memory. The only scenario is that PHP itself has a (security) bug, which you can mitigate by keeping PHP up to date.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using preg_match to check for proper formatting, I wouldn't do anything with user input without checking its length first.  I could probably come up with a 10,000 character string that would pass a simple formatting check.

Comment: Only probably? ;)  If you put a too-long value into a database using PDO, will it truncate or just fail?